# randomly select unique element from array coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I want to randomly select an element from an array that's not already present in another array in coffeescript.

Is there anything in coffeescript that makes that easier? How could that be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not particularly CoffeeScript-ish, but something like this would do the trick:

```
filterAndRandomSelect = (arr1, arr2) ->
  filtered = (i for i in arr1 when i not in arr2) #this is pretty cute
  filtered[Math.floor(Math.random() * filtered.length)]

console.log filterAndRandomSelect [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5]
```

Of course, that 'cute' CS line could just as easily be:

```
filtered = arr1.filter (val) -> val not in arr2
```

which is also kinda cute.